# Where is NSControl's addTarget() method?

Tags: swift, nsbutton, nscontrol

So I haven't looked at Swift/Cocoa in several years. I just created a simple macOS app using Xcode 10.0 and see that `NSControl` no longer has an `addTarget(...)` method. It looks like it was replaced by a `target` property of type `id`.

How do I go about adding handlers for things like button clicks now since I need to specify the action (e.g. click), object to be called, and the selector to call on that object.

---

**Solution:**

```
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
statusItem.button?.target = self
statusItem.button?.action = #selector(didClick(_:))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, the method based syntax `foo.addTarget(self)` has been replaced with the property based syntax `foo.target = self`. It still exists in `UIKit` because in Cocoa Touch you have to specify also the control event.

And all relevant `NSControl` subclasses have `init` methods to pass `target` and `action`

Comment: Thank you @vadian. Unfortunately, I'm still a bit confused as I'm not the one creating the button. How do I specify which method gets called, say for a click event, when I'm only indicating that the object to be called is `self` with `foo.target = self`?

Comment: There is also an `action` property to specify the selector.

Comment: Did `NSControl` have a `addTarget:` method? As far as I know, `NSControl` always had one target and a `setTarget:` method.

Answer (score -2):

It's still there...  You might want to review the docs as refresher.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget

Comment: The question is about NSControl from Cocoa (macOS), not about UIControl from Cocoa Touch (iOS).